# How do i get subset of a data frame where Column A value equals Column B value in R ( Data read from CSV)

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to create a subset of a data frame :

**Original Data frame looks like :**

```
Column A     Column B    Column C 
---------------------------------
  22        22             30
  18        35             28
  25        25             29
  25        42             22
  75        75             33
```

**I would like to get subset where Column-A value == Column-B Value , End result would look like :**

```
Column A     Column B    Column C 
---------------------------------
      22        22             30
      25        25             29
      75        75             33
```

Is there any 1 liner solution to achieve this ? Thanks!

**Note :** I read data from CSV (I haven't provided this data point in original post , sorry).

I get an error when i try : df[df$Column.A==df$Column.B,]

Error in Ops.factor(df$ColumnA, df$ColumnB) :
  level sets of factors are different

Comment: `subset(df1, Column.A == Column.B)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a one-liner:

```
df1[df1$Column.A==df1$Column.B,]
#  Column.A Column.B Column.C
#1       22       22       30
#3       25       25       29
#5       75       75       33
```

**data**

```
df1 <- read.table(text="Column.A     Column.B    Column.C 
                             22        22             30
                             18        35             28
                             25        25             29
                             25        42             22
                             75        75             33", header=T)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. After debugging further i realized problem is not with the command :) . Sorry for not providing all data points in initial post. Problem has been resolved after i tried : read.csv("~/my.csv",as.is=TRUE).